# PL/SQL Return Only 1 Row for Each Grouping

Tags: plsql

I have table that lists items like below. It basically has Operation Numbers (OP_NO) that tell where a product is at in the process. These OP Numbers can be either Released or Completed. They follow a process as in 10 must happen before 20, 20 must happen before 30 etc. However users do not update all steps in reality so we end up with some items out of order complete while the earlier steps are not as show below (OP30 is completed but OP 10 and 20 are not).

I basically want to produce a listing of each ORDER_ID showing the furthest point of completion for each ORDER_ID. I figured I could do this by querying for STATUS = 'Completed' and Sorting by OP_NO Desc. However I can't figure out how to produce only 1 result for each ORDER_ID. For example in ORDER_ID 345 Steps 10 and 20 are completed. I would only want to return that STEP 20 is where it is currently at. I was figuring I could do this with 'WHERE ROWNUM <= 1' but haven't had much luck. Could any experts weigh in?

Thanks!

```
ORDER_ID | ORDER_SEC | ORDER_RELEASE | OP_NO | STATUS     | Description
123        2           3               10      Released     Op10
123        2           3               20      Released     Op20
123        2           3               30      Completed    Op30
123        2           3               40      Released     Op40
345        1           8               10      Completed    Op10
345        1           8               20      Completed    Op20
345        1           8               30      Released     Op30
345        1           8               40      Released     Op40
```

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want the below should do what you need.  Just replace test table with your table name.

```
select * 
from test_table tst 
where status = 'Completed'
and op_no = (select max(op_no) 
             from test_table tst1 
             where tst.order_id = tst1.order_id 
             and status = 'Completed');
```

Given your sample data this produced the below results.

```
Order_Id  Order_Sec   Order_Release   op_no  Status       Description
123       2           3               30     Completed    Op30
345       1           8               20     Completed    Op20
```

Cheers

Shaun Peterson